# Using any() function for value of 1.5

Tags: python, numpy, arraylist

I want to know if any of the values contained in a 1024 length array are greater than the value 1.2. I've found the median value of the array and its 1.1, so I know the array contains values that are higher and lower than 1. The code that I'm using is shown below and the resulting message i'm getting is "No signal present".

```
  if in1_norm.any()>=1.2:   ## Comparison of array to threshold. Using   
                            ## a generic value for now 
       print "A signal is present"
  else: 
       print "No signal is present"
```

I've read in a previous post that any() evaluates as a value of 1 or "true, so, I believe I'm not getting the correct result because the comparison is viewed as 1>=1.2, which is false. Is there any other way of doing this??
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The part `in1_norm.any()>=1.2` will not do what you're intended. The `any()` function returns True if any of the array's items can be evaluated as True otherwise it will return False. You need to first compare your items with `1.2` then call the any on the results.

```
(in1_norm >= 1.2).any()
```